# Lua admin script for roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like to know if you could help me with a Roblox script. From chat admin, when I say `!kill user` I want to the user to be killed. This is all I could do:

```
target = "Woozy"
Player.Chatted:connect(function(cht)
    if cht:match("!kill") then
         Kill(target)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use ! prefix (maybe),
Second, you need to add `local` before `target`, Third, do `Kill(target)` code really kills you?, Fourth, you need to add `end)` for end of your function.

Try insert ModuleChat into Chat library then copy this code to the script

```
local AdminCommands = require(1163352238)
local Utilities = AdminCommands.Utilities
 
function killPlayer(commandData)
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
end
 
AdminCommands:BindCommand({"kill"}, killPlayer, 1, "Kill the user")
 
return AdminCommands.Run
```

Then type /kill. Your command should ready now.

I got it from Roblox Developer Article. You can check that [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Chat-Modules)

You can unbind the command too, using this code

```
AdminCommands:UnbindCommand({"kill"})
```